# Changing background image, headline and copy on reload

Tags: php, image, text, background, reload

Is it possible with either Jquery or PHP to create a homepage with a changing background image and tagline/copy on reload.

I'm using a full image background on a client website and I have specific headlines and copy that go with each background image. My plan was to used 4-6 images and taglines/copy.

I don't want to make the text part of the background image because that will do me no favors with the search engines.

I know how to code it to change the background image on reload or the copy but not both at the same time. And I've had little luck finding a solution that satisfies both of these requirements.

I'm really a designer and not a programmer, so go easy on me, But if anyone knows of a solution, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Its possible and I should imagine there are many ways. Look up how its done and give it a go. When you hit problems then we can help

Comment: That's the problem. I've been doing web searches all weekend and I've yet to find a solution. I'm glad that it's possible but I don't know how to do it. I need a resource, link, tutorial, script, plug-in or something.

Answer (score 0):

You want to randomly pick a background image and some text every time the user reloads. This should be pretty easy. You could do this all in either Javascript or PHP. I'm going for PHP.

Do this near the top of your file:

```
<?php

    // Generate a random number.
    $random = rand(0, 2);

    // Set up messages, and fetch a random one.
    $messages = array(
        array("heading" => "foo", "body" => "123"), 
        array("heading" => "bar", "body" => "456"),
        array("heading" => "bad", "body" => "789")
    );
    $message = $messages[$random];

?>
```

Then, further down the PHP file, in your HTML:

```
<body class="background-<?= $random ?>">
    <h1><?= $message['heading'] ?></h1>
    <p><?= $message['body'] ?></p>
</body>
```

And you can do the background image randomisation in your CSS:

```
body.background-0 { background: red; }
body.background-1 { background: green; }
body.background-2 { background: blue; }
```

Comment: First off, Thank you for responding.

Is that going to attach specific headlines to each background image though or is it going to randomly assign a headline with any of the images. I have headlines that have to go with certain images.

Comment: It'll match the two. So `foo` will always be `background-0`, `bar` will be `1`, and so on. PHP numbers things starting from 0.

Comment: one other question: if the I needed to had a small paragraph to attach under each heading, what would I need to add to the PHP to accomplish this?

Comment: Well the random color is working but no headings or copy are showing up.http://www.hoopersbazaar.com/test/

Comment: Where (and how) are you echoing `$message`?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not very fluent in PHP. I placed
 <h1><?= $message['heading'] ?></h1>
    <p><?= $message['body'] ?></p> in a page on wordpress.

Comment: Any more info on what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it's stupid little detail I left out. It's in the code on this test page. @Sam

http://www.hoopersbazaar.com/test/

Comment: I'd need to see the source code of the page. Can you post it somewhere like pastebin.com or gist.github.com?

Comment: Try posting the source of the whole page.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4uQcVUvG @sam whole source.  This is just a wordpress template I threw up to test this on BTW.